# Create multiple related objects in form, Django template

Tags: django, templates, model

I'm new to Django and im trying to create a recipebook. I want to create a recipe and in the same form add a variable number of ingredients. In the form the user should be able to fill in one ingredient and click a button to add another as needed.

Here are my models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipe_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    instructions = models.TextField(blank=False)
    tips = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    course = models.ForeignKey("Course", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", related_name='recipes', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Unit(models.Model):

    unit = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit


class Ingredient(models.Model):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ingredients")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):

    course = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course


class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Tag(models.Model):

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

I'm breaking my head over how to do this in the template. I could create a form for the recipe with a modelform and create a seperate list with javascript for the ingredients and send in in json to the backend but that seems off.

I hope you understand my quiestion, any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: why not ajax, its really helpful

Comment: Well, im not sure how to implement it. When the form is submitted the recipe has to be created before i create the ingredients. But i that means i cant be sure if the ingredients are valid, so i could end up with a recipe that has no ingredients. So in my head there should be a ingredientform inside a recipeform, but that is where my brain short circuits, i cant figure out how i can get a variable number of ingredients in there.

Comment: you can just create multiple forms for each class, and just use `modelformset_factory` for adding ingredients. of course, it still does need ajax. you can just iron out the errors through validation.